# How to deliver a desktop app of Kotlin multiplatform project?

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform

I don't see in documentations.  When I build a multiplatform compose project based on JVM, how can I deliver a desktop package or app so others can execute it easily?

==========

Update:

I specified the following in build.gradle.kts under desktop

```
compose.desktop {
    application {
        mainClass = "MainKt"
        javaHome = System.getenv("JDK_18")
        nativeDistributions {
            targetFormats(TargetFormat.Dmg, TargetFormat.Msi, TargetFormat.Deb)
            packageName = "MyApp"
            packageVersion = "1.0.0"
        }
    }
}
```

Then running `./gradlew packageDeb` (on Ubuntu) I got a .deb package, which I could install on Ubuntu and run.  Very cool.  (It looks there is no option building it from Intellij and I have to do it with gradlew)

Then I tried `./gradlew packageMsi`, it came back very quickly saying build successful, but I get no .msi file generated.  Do I have to build it from a Windows machine?

I haven't tried to build the dmg for Mac as it's advised to use XCode on the Mac to generate a signed version.

==============

Update 1:

So based on description of [jPackage](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/jpackage/packaging-overview.html#GUID-C1027043-587D-418D-8188-EF8F44A4C06A) from Oracle:

> Application packages must be built on the target platform. The system
> used for packaging must contain the application, a JDK, and software
> needed by the packaging tool.
>
> To package your application for multiple platforms, you must run the
> packaging tool on each platform. If you want more than one format for
> a platform, you must run the tool once for each format.

Comment: I gave you this link: https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-jb/tree/master/tutorials/Native_distributions_and_local_execution, under your previous question, what's not clear there?

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I read that (not seen that you gave me on the previous question).  What I am not clear is that it's meant for a native compose project rather than JVM project.  Or I am missing the point?

Comment: Just for the future, any [underlined](https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-jb/tree/master/tutorials/Native_distributions_and_local_execution) text on StackOverflow is a link, like my [documentation link](https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-jb/tree/master/tutorials/Native_distributions_and_local_execution) under the previous question.

Comment: In most multiplatform technologies, you have to use native methods to distribute, for example, the installer you create for windows will be a native installer, and your JVM application will be inside the package.

Comment: @Pylyp Dukhov, I updated my question.  Would you please advise?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have such experience. I guess that Windows may be required to create a build, but even in this case there should be an error when trying to build from other platforms, you can [report](https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-jb/issues/new) it as a bug.